# How to add new line in setText in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, settext

I want to show table like this..

```
2*1=2
2*2=4 //UPTO 10 Times
```

but instead it is showing this..
2*10=20 only
I have added this line in xml code

```
 android:lines="10"
 android:maxLines="10"
```

please check the code buddy!!

```
String s= editTextNumber.getText().toString() ;
           

int t= Integer.parseInt(s);
               int p=0,i;
               for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
               {
                   p= t*i ;
                  textView2.setText( t+"*"+i+"=" +p+"\n" ) ;

               }
```